# Belongs to user association with polymorphic routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, polymorphism

I have a small application where I have downtowns and I have properties. Each downtown has many properties and each property has one downtown.

In my controller I had things set to allow for any new properties to be created under the umbrella of a downtown but now I decided to add users into the mix..... The problem i'm having is getting an existing user the acknowledgements of owning one of the models it created.

My existing controller related methods are below. I was thinking the line by adding `@property.user_id = current_user.id` would take care of it. However if I then run a `Property.last.user`

I get a `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.property_id:`

```
# GET /downtowns/1/properties/new
def new
  set_downtown
  @property = @downtown.properties.new
end

# POST /downtowns/1/properties
def create
  set_downtown
  @property = @downtown.properties.new(property_params)
  @property.user_id = current_user.id

  if @property.save
    redirect_to @downtown
  else
    render :new
  end
end

private

def set_downtown
  @downtown = Downtown.includes(:properties).find(params[:downtown_id])
end
```

In my models

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :properties
  has_many :downtowns
end

class Property < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :downtown
  belongs_to :user

  has_one :user  
end
```

Don't know if i need to paste this, but my routes files is

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root :to => "downtowns#index"
  resources :cities

  resources :downtowns do
    resources :properties
  end
end
```

If anybody would be able to take a look at this, I truly would be grateful! Thank you so much!

Comment: It seems you have to users(has_one and belongs_to) in the Property class. Do you need the [has_one :user] line in the Property class?

Comment: can you show your schema for users and property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :downtown
  belongs_to :user
end
```

You want to use a `belongs_to` association as the foreign key column is on *this* model. The inverse of a `has_many` association is always a `belongs_to` association.

If you declare two associations with the same name as you have done the later association will always overwrite the former.

You also almost never need (or want) to explicitly use the `_id=` setter. Use the `user=` setter instead.

```
before_action :set_downtown, only: [:new, :create, :index] # DRY

# POST /downtowns/1/properties
def create
  @property = @downtown.properties.new(property_params) do |p|
    p.user = current_user
  end
  if @property.save
    redirect_to @downtown
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! I tested it out and it worked super well.  One quick question i do have is, do you know why it is better to use `user=` instead of `_id=` ? (i've switched to `user=` per your suggestion, but i'm still a little curious)

Comment: Because it does not expose the implementation details. That's kind of the whole point of abstractions like ActiveRecord associations.

Answer (score 2):

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.property_id

because you have `has_one :user` in `Property`. Which means `user` is holding the `id` of the `Property` as `property_id`.

instead `Property` is holding the `User#id` as `user_id`.

remove `has_one :user`

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :downtown
  belongs_to :user      # this table has user_id
end
```